# Java SSL using java-websockets - Connection Refused

Tags: java, ssl, java-websocket

I have been trying to change an existing websocket implementation from using WS to WSS for about a week now with no luck. I have tried to follow many examples online and get various errors. The end goal here is to have a webpage connect through SSL to my java application that is running a websocket. So first I figured it would be good to try and get two java applications to be able to connect before I involve the webpage to replace the java client.

I have generated a keystore, cert and trust store using the following:

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -validity 3650 -keystore "C:\users\user\Desktop\fb1dasslkeystore.jks" -storepass "test11" -keypass "test11" -alias "FB1DASSL" -dname "CN=127.0.0.1, OU=CA, O=Company, L=Location, S=State, C=USA"
```

Here I migrated it to pkcs12 like it suggested:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore C:\users\user\Desktop\fb1dasslkeystore.jks -destkeystore C:\users\user\Desktop\fb1dasslkeystore.jks -deststoretype pkcs12

keytool -export -alias FB1DASSL -keystore C:\users\user\Desktop\fb1dasslkeystore.jks -file C:\users\user\Desktop\fb1da.cert

keytool -import -file C:\users\user\Desktop\fb1da.cert -alias FB1DASSL -keystore C:\users\user\desktop\mytruststore.jts
```

I then took the cert and imported it into my Trusted Certificate spot in Windows using "Manage Computer Certificates" and loading it under Trusted Root Certification Authority (for the later web stuff).

Then attempted to run my server and client but keep getting a "Connection Refused". Or I get javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target.

**TestServerMain**

```
public class TestServer
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String STORETYPE = "JKS";
        String KEYSTORE = new File("C:\\users\\user\\Desktop\\fb1dasslkeystore.jks").getAbsolutePath();
        String STOREPASSWORD = "test11";
        String KEYPASSWORD = "test11";
        // now start the websocket server

        KeyStore ks;
        try
        {
            jWsServer ws = new jWsServer(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 8888));

            ks = KeyStore.getInstance(STORETYPE);

            File kf = new File(KEYSTORE);
            ks.load(new FileInputStream(kf), STOREPASSWORD.toCharArray());

            KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
            kmf.init(ks, KEYPASSWORD.toCharArray());
            TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
            tmf.init(ks);

            SSLContext sslContext = null;
            sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

            ws.setWebSocketFactory(new DefaultSSLWebSocketServerFactory(sslContext));

            ws.start();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(String.format("Websocket server started on port = %d", 8888));
    }

}
```

**Server class**

```
public class jWsServer extends WebSocketServer
{
    static Logger errorLog = LogManager.getLogger(jWsServer.class.getName());

    /**
     * Constructor, where caller specifies non-default port number
     * 
     * @param port socket port number
     * @throws UnknownHostException
     */
    public jWsServer(int port) throws UnknownHostException
    {
        super(new InetSocketAddress(port));
    }

    /**
     * Constructor, where caller specifies non-default socket address
     * 
     * @param address socket address
     */
    public jWsServer(InetSocketAddress address)
    {
        super(address);
    }

    /**
     * Event that fires when a client sends a message
     * 
     * @param conn client WebSocket object handle
     * @param message message string, should be JSON string for a request
     */
    @Override
    public void onMessage(WebSocket conn, String message)
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Message Recieved : " + message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("ERROR: Can't add request to session " + conn);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Event that fires when a connection error occurs
     * 
     * @param conn client WebSocket object handle
     * @param ex exception that occurred
     */
    @Override
    public void onError(WebSocket conn, Exception ex)
    {
        if (conn != null)
        {
            System.out.println("ERROR: " + conn + " onError()" + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClose(WebSocket conn, int code, String reason, boolean remote)
    {
        System.out.println("Disconnecting client connId=" + conn.hashCode() + " Reason=" + code);
    }

    @Override
    public void onOpen(WebSocket conn, ClientHandshake handshake)
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Connecting client connId=" + conn.hashCode());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("ERROR: Can't create session or add it to queue");
        }
        errorLog.info("Websocket open.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(this.getAddress().getHostString());

    }
}
```

**Client Main**

```
public class Test
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        String location;

        location = "wss://127.0.0.1:8888";
        System.out.println("Using location: \'" + location + "\'");
        try
        {
            new MyClient(location);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**Client Class**

```
public class MyClient
{
    private WebSocketClient cc;

    public MyClient(String location)
    {
        try
        {

            cc = new WebSocketClient(new URI(location))
            {

                @Override
                public void onMessage(String message)
                {
                    System.out.println("got: " + message + "\n");
                }

                @Override
                public void onOpen(ServerHandshake handshake)
                {
                    System.out.println("You are connected to ChatServer: " + getURI() + "\n");
                }

                @Override
                public void onClose(int code, String reason, boolean remote)
                {
                    System.out.println(
                            "You have been disconnected from: " + getURI() + "; Code: " + code + " " + reason
                                    + "\n");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Exception ex)
                {
                    System.out.println("Exception occurred ...\n" + ex + "\n");
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            };
            cc.connect();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: not a complete solution but at least a part of the problem seems likely to be the common name is set as `CN=10.0.0.14` but the host you're connecting to is `127.0.0.1`. You can add a SAN (part of the x509 extensions.. entries can be `IP:` and/or `DNS:`) or try change the CN `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Thanks Rob. I fixed that in the question. I have been cycling through trying to use 127.0.0.1, localhost and my machines real IP address and I just mixed that up when copying it. I make sure to match them with the cert generation when I switch.

Comment: It was a copy paste error in the question so probably not the issue.

Comment: still doesnt match throughout. You have 10.0.0.4 in some places and 127.0.0.1 in others. If the host in the CN is not consistent with the host address you're connecting to it will fail.

Comment: Got it. BTW do you know what error I'd get if they were mismatched?

Comment: Generally speaking I’ve had very poor feedback in relation to ssl errors.. failed connection/handshake failed is typically all you’ll see. You can enter debug mode and step down into library code if it helps but if it gets all the way down to reading the certs and all you get back is a vague exception it doesn’t help you much. I’ve typically found ssl fails when CN doesn’t match the host specified by the client.

Comment: Rob, seems to have finally worked. Once I lined up the IP addresses and added them to all the cacerts stuff it worked. Now I need to get the client to be a webpage instead of a java program.

Comment: good stuff! Glad its working as normally I comment and never hear back whether it worked.

Comment: Sadly it doesn't seem to work from webpage connection though. I have a digicert keystore, should I be using that as the base instead of generating one? Or any other ideas for that?